# My getLastRow() is giving me as result the last row +2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use lastRow(); but its giving me the the last row + 2 rows and I can't find the reason.
Can anyone take a quick look and tell me why?
[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nXaYH80mMUh-VCWqn-gv-7T1fKQCmqz88x7pU0nEFdY/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function myFunction() {
  var originSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var originSheet = originSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var datos = originSheet.getRange(4,5,originSheet.getLastRow(),4).setBackground('red');

console.log(datos.getA1Notation());  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
var datos = originSheet.getRange(4, 5, originSheet.getLastRow()-3, 4).setBackground('red');
```

the third argument is the **number of rows** and not the final row, since you are beginning at row #4, you have to minus by 3

Comment: Wow Thank You Mike for the quick help, your the best!